# Best practice when handling different objects in a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Lets for instance say i want to create a tableView containing multiple different pets. However each pet has different attributes and values. This could easily be done by creating a SuperClass called `Pet` and then SubClass with for instance `Dog` and `Bird`. However is this best practice and how would i be able to add all these different Objects into 1 tableView without making 2 different sections. What is best practice for this?

Comment: It is a good practice. If you only want one section just fill an array with pets and type check while dequeuing the cells. Nothing wrong there no need to overthink I believe

Comment: But how can i retrieve the individual attributes in each subclass then?

Comment: Just check to see what type of pet it is and then responds accordingly. Now if your cells all have different properties based on the type of pet, and the cells look different, now we should think about using different sections in which case I would fill a dictionary as your data source and get the pets for each section as needed

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the types of variables, and how you want to display them differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned, a `superClass` for the `pets` would be a good way to go about it. Then adding all the `pet objects` into some `collection object` like an `NSArray` for use with the `UITableView`.

As for the number of sections - that's purely a `UI` design decision you need to make and should not be based on how your dataSource is structured.

Comment: but for instance if i had a subclass `Dog` and another `Bird`. How can i then add these to same collection and populate in tableView? these subclasses have their own variables.